# Assembly redirect being ignored in machine.config. In web.config works

Tags: web-config, assembly-resolution, assembly-references, machine.config

I have two versions of a dll.
I am seeing a unexpected behaviour.
When I add the assembly redirect to web.config it works , but when it is added at machine.config I get some errors inside my app caused by the loading of old version of the library.
I dont get to undertsand why is that happening.

- I am sure I am editing the correct machine.config since other changes on it take effect in the app.
- I need the change to be inside machine.config since it´s a server with a lot of apps which need to have the redirection.

Whats going on???

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>

            <assemblyIdentity name="My.Library" publicKeyToken="..removed in stackoverflow...." culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<runtime/>` was duplicated in machine.config. Be careful with that sice it does not throws exceptions.